# Debugging in vs 2008 firefox 3.5+

Tags: javascript

well i was wondering how will i enable javascript debugging because even after entering the break point the debugger is not stopping there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visual studio will only debug a page open in IE. in visual studio you can select debug -> attach to process and find the appropriate process for the browser window. alternatively you can type

```
javascript:debugger;
```

in the address bar and you should be prompted to debug the page, where you can then choose visual studio as a debugger. the html page you're looking at will be listed under the solution items. you can set a breakpoint in the page and as long as you're still debugging it'll stop there next time it's hit. note that in IE's settings you have to uncheck the boxes that say "disable script debugging".

for firefox, get the firebug addon. you can bring up the console with f12 and manually set a breakpoint or use the address bar trick above. you'll have to enable script debugging in firebug before it will stop for anything.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using firefox to test, I suggest FIREBUG http://getfirebug.com/. It's awesome! And of course it allows setting break points and debugging functions that are easy to use.

Comment: ok thanks i know about the firebug ,microsoft has provided javascript debuggin in 2008+ so  i am trying to use that